# I have getting problem saving a dynamic programming problem called partition equal subset sum

Tags: java, dynamic-programming

I am sorry to be posting this question, but i am new to dp and I have been doing some problems to get the concept. In the problem, I am given an array and I need to tell if I can divide the array into 2 subsets such that they have the same sum.

Problem  -

[image]

What I am doing - 
I first calculate the sum of the array and return false if the sum is not divisible by 2. If not I go on to use to bottom-up approach of the knapsack problem solve this problem.

```
class Solution {
    boolean[][] dp;
    // using the knapsack problem that i know
    public boolean canPartition(int[] nums) {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int num : nums){
            sum += num;
        }
        // we have the sum;
        if(sum % 2 == 1){
            return false;
        }
        // else do other things
        sum = sum / 2;
        dp = new boolean[nums.length + 1][sum + 1];
        // initiation of the array
        for(int i = 0; i < dp.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < dp[0].length; j++){
                if(i == 0 && j == 0){
                    dp[i][j] = true;
                }else if(i == 0){
                    dp[i][j] = false;
                }else if(j == 0){
                    dp[i][j] = true;
                }
            }
        }
        helper(nums, sum);
        for(int i = 0; i < dp.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < dp[0].length; j++){
                System.out.print(dp[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        return dp[nums.length][sum];
    }

    // i and j are the indexes that we are trying to access right now
    public void helper(int[] nums, int sum){
        for(int i = 1; i < nums.length; i++){
            for(int j = 1; j < sum + 1; j++){
                if(nums[i - 1] <= j){
                    dp[i][j] =  dp[i][j - nums[i - 1]] || dp[i - 1][j]; 
                }else{
                    dp[i][j] = dp[i - 1][j];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Printing my dp matrix at the end I get this - 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed the equality in your helper function `for loop i < nums.length` should be for(int i = 1; i <= nums.length; i++) . Also your array initialization shouldn't be so complex . Check the code below which works fine

```
class Solution {
    boolean[][] dp;
    // using the knapsack problem that i know
    public boolean canPartition(int[] nums) {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int num : nums){
            sum += num;
        }
        // we have the sum;
        if(sum % 2 == 1){
            return false;
        }
        // else do other things
        sum = sum / 2;
        dp = new boolean[nums.length + 1][sum + 1];
        // initiation of the array
        for(int i = 0; i<dp.length; i++)
            dp[i][0]=true;                 // clean initialization 

        for(int i = 1; i <= nums.length; i++){ // added i==nums.length
            for(int j = 1; j <=sum ; j++){

                dp[i][j] = dp[i - 1][j];  // changed
                if(nums[i - 1] <= j){
                  dp[i][j]=dp[i-1][j-nums[i-1]]||dp[i-1][j]; 


                }
            }
        }
        return dp[nums.length][sum];
    }

}
```